# How to find or remove a command block from a world

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

Long story short, had some script kiddies join my realm and place down a bunch of command blocks around the world that do a variety of things (the biggest issue atm being a `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ fill ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ tnt`)

I need to find command blocks all over the rendered world and NBTExplorer/MCEdit/MCCToolChestPE won't even recognize the worlds I have for Bedrock and Amulet is useless for what I need done.

Is there anything else that could help me find these things?

Comment: You could try to disable commands on the world while finding the command blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do.

Hop into Creative mode and see whether or not the command blocks stop when you leave certain areas. This should allow you to pinpoint their position within a few chunks. Make sure no one else is online and also set your render chunks low.

If they remain active no matter where you are then they are in the spawn chunks.

Then set up your own command block with a command which replaces all command blocks within say a 16 x 16 x 16 and fly around the area till the command says a block has been replaced. You could also do the same for TNT which would remove the blocks being placed on you.

`execute <yourname> ~ ~ ~ fill ~-8 ~-8 ~-8 ~8 ~8 ~8 air 0 replace command_block`